# Custom Add and Edit Record Dialog in Infragistics Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid, infragistics, ignite-ui

I am working on Infragistics Grid in MVC and want to do some customization in it.
The issue is that data which I am showing is different than the inputs I am taking from the user (the editors in row editing/adding mode). There is additional processing needed to be done before displaying in a grid.

Infragistics grid provides a good mechanism to show the JSON object array which nice UI and events which works fine for me. The problem comes when I want to Edit a particular Row or Add New. For this Infragistics provides its own UI for it. Or in case we want to customize it, it doesn't provide much room to do so. It just allows providing a template for columns like the following:

```
<script id="rowEditDialogRowTemplate1" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">      
          <tr class="tableBackGround">                  
                <td class="labelBackGround"> ${headerText}
                </td>
                <td data-key='${dataKey}'>
                      <input /> 
                </td>
          </tr>
</script>
```

But I want to provide an entire template which will have my custom form and form elements.

I want a simple Infragistics Grid which will just show the data. If I click Add New within the grid then it will load my dialog. 
If I double-click any row it will again open my dialog where I can edit the things. Later, once I save the data, I'll make a server trip and refresh the grid accordingly.

**To summarize**

I want to provide my own custom Form for Add and Edit in Infragistics Grid. And I'll take care of reloading the Grid after saving the data.

Reference : **[Infragistics Grid](http://help.infragistics.com/jQuery/2012.2//ui.igGridUpdating#!options)**

Please help me to get this done!

Answer (score 2):

You have found the correct API reference - in the 'options' tab look for the **rowEditDialogTemplate** option.
The use of the default Row Edit Template (yes, it can be used for adding rows as well) is shown in [the official sample](http://www.infragistics.com/products/jquery/sample/grid/row-edit-template).

You can also find out more about it in the help topics: [Row Edit Template](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/jQuery/2013.1/CLR4.0/html/igGrid_Updating_RowEditTemplate.html) and [Configuring Row Edit Template](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/jQuery/2013.1/CLR4.0/html/igGrid_Updating_RowEditTemplate_Configuring.html).

Also, in the Infragistics forums you can find additional info on how to utilize the igGridUpdating feature's API methods (addRow and updateRow for example) with your fully custom form for row adding and editing.

Comment: I didn't found rowEditDialogTemplate in reference

Comment: @KD - in the "options" tab you can find a lot of options for the template - just search for "roweditdialog" and you'll see all 8 options. Also, of note is that there are 6 events for the editing template which you can utilize.

Comment: i think you have not customized infragistic grid yet Borislav :)
there is not a straight way to add a customized form via those options

Comment: @KD please clarify what you are having difficulty with as the Row Edit Template will display whatever you put on it.  Is that not working for you?